# replace columns with NaN based on a string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-applymap

I have the below data frame

```
ipdb> csv_data
  country_edited sale_edited  date_edited  transformation_edited
0          India      403171     20090101                     10
1         Bhutan      394096     20090101                     20
2          Nepal    Set Null     20090101                     30
3         madhya      355883     20090101                     40
4          sudan    Set Null     20090101                     50
```

I want to replace all the column values that contain `Set Null` to `Nan` and so i approached below way

```
import numpy

def set_NaN(element):
    if element == 'Set Null':
        return numpy.nan
    else:
        return element

csv_data = csv_data.applymap(lambda element: set_NaN(element))
```

But it does not changes anything

```
ipdb> print csv_data
  country_edited sale_edited  date_edited  transformation_edited
0          India      403171     20090101                     10
1         Bhutan      394096     20090101                     20
2          Nepal    Set Null     20090101                     30
3         madhya      355883     20090101                     40
4          sudan    Set Null     20090101                     50
ipdb>
```

But when i print only `csv_data.applymap(lambda element: set_NaN(element))` as below i can see the output, but when assigned back i can't get the data i intended to

```
ipdb> csv_data.applymap(lambda element: set_NaN(element))
  country_edited sale_edited  date_edited  transformation_edited
0          India      403171     20090101                     10
1         Bhutan      394096     20090101                     20
2          Nepal         NaN     20090101                     30
3         madhya      355883     20090101                     40
4          sudan         NaN     20090101                     50
```

So how to replace the column values with NaN based on certain string ?

Comment: Do you get anything here: `csv_data = csv_data.applymap(set_NaN)`. Also, `applymap` takes a callable, so that additional `lambda` is unnecessary here.

Comment: Ok i don't know it, i am new to pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html), it replace `True` values of mask by `NaN`. Also some columns are numeric, so need cast values of `df` to `string` first:

```
print (csv_data.astype(str) == 'Set Null')
  country_edited sale_edited date_edited transformation_edited
0          False       False       False                 False
1          False       False       False                 False
2          False        True       False                 False
3          False       False       False                 False
4          False        True       False                 False


csv_data = csv_data.mask(csv_data.astype(str) == 'Set Null')
print (csv_data)
  country_edited sale_edited  date_edited  transformation_edited
0          India      403171     20090101                     10
1         Bhutan      394096     20090101                     20
2          Nepal         NaN     20090101                     30
3         madhya      355883     20090101                     40
4          sudan         NaN     20090101                     50
```

Another solution with `numpy boolean mask` - compare numpy array by [`DataFrame.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
print (csv_data.values == 'Set Null')
[[False False False False]
 [False False False False]
 [False  True False False]
 [False False False False]
 [False  True False False]]

csv_data = csv_data.mask(csv_data.values == 'Set Null')
print (csv_data)
  country_edited sale_edited  date_edited  transformation_edited
0          India      403171     20090101                     10
1         Bhutan      394096     20090101                     20
2          Nepal         NaN     20090101                     30
3         madhya      355883     20090101                     40
4          sudan         NaN     20090101                     50
```

In your solution is necessary assign data back to `csv_data`:

```
def set_NaN(element):
    if element == 'Set Null':
        return numpy.nan
    else:
        return element

csv_data = csv_data.applymap(lambda element: set_NaN(element))
print (csv_data)
  country_edited sale_edited  date_edited  transformation_edited
0          India      403171     20090101                     10
1         Bhutan      394096     20090101                     20
2          Nepal         NaN     20090101                     30
3         madhya      355883     20090101                     40
4          sudan         NaN     20090101                     50
```